# Using gleam, cannot import 'gleam/otp/process'

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gleam

Using Gleam, what is best practice for spawning a process:

```
import gleam/io
import gleam/http
import gleam/http/response
import gleam/http/request
import gleam/int
import gleam/otp/process  // <<<< this does not exist?


pub fn handle_request(_req: request) -> response {
  process.spawn(fn() { io.println(int.to_string(5)) })
  response.ok("Processed request in a new process")
}

pub fn main() {
  let settings = http.default_settings()
  http.start(settings, handle_request)
}
```

the problem is `import gleam/otp/process` is not a thing - how to import that? I get a compile error with this import.

Comment: ¿Perhaps you meant to import `gleam/erlang/process` from https://github.com/gleam-lang/erlang? `gleam/otp/process` seems to be moved to `gleam_erlang` two years ago https://github.com/gleam-lang/otp/blob/0b9301c223c30eda0581e99f09a5be911d9867fd/CHANGELOG.md#v050---2022-08-09